# Rails use ruby in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of hard coding a link description, I would like to use some Ruby code.

This is the original:

```
<li><%= link_to "Open Projects List", workorders_index2_path %></li>
```

This didn't work for me:

```
<li><%= link_to "<%= current_tenant.name_workorder.capitalize.pluralize %>", workorders_index2_path %></li>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use quotes at all:

```
<li><%= link_to current_tenant.name_workorder.capitalize.pluralize, workorders_index2_path %></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already ARE using ruby code.  `<%= %>` everything inside of that is pure ruby.  `link_to` is a ruby method, and "Open Projects List" is the first parameter to that method, it's a string.  Anything you can do in ruby you can send here - don't send a string, send the variable:

```
<li><%= link_to current_tenant.name_workorder.to_s.capitalize.pluralize, workorders_index2_path %></li>
```

You can also use string interpolation like you would with regular ruby:

```
<li><%= link_to "Open Project #{current_tenant.name_workorder}", workorders_index2_path %></li>
```